# Gratuitous vertical space with nested list environments given a certain line length

Tags: beamer, spacing

In the following MWE the simple addition of ":" causes some extra vertical spacing to appear before the nested `enumerate` environment, despite the fact that adding ":" does not cause the text to split across another line. Any idea what's going on?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{itemize}
    \item{Actional verbs appeared in full \emph{be}-passive, full \emph{get}-passive, and active
        \begin{enumerate}[(1)]
            \item{\ldots}
        \end{enumerate}
    }
    \item{Actional verbs appeared in full \emph{be}-passive, full \emph{get}-passive, and active:
        \begin{enumerate}[(1)]
            \item{\ldots}
        \end{enumerate}
    }
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The question here is *why* this is happening. That is, I'm happy to just leave out the ":" for the `beamer` presentation that I'm putting together, so I'm not particularly interested in a 'solution' to the 'problem'. I'm just curious why this is happening and whether this is by design in `beamer`.

(Note: the effect is dependent on use of this particular theme. <del>Although, if this is underlyingly an issue with `beamer` one could presumably construct analogous cases for other themes.</del> Although, if this is underlyingly an issue with (La)TeX (see update), one could presumably construct analogous cases in other `beamer` themes *and* other document classes that exhibit this behavior. (Although, see update 2.))

---

**Update**:

As per some of the comments and [@Thruston's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155905/32888), I thought I would update the question.

<del>First, I've removed the `beamer` tag, as this does not seem to be about `beamer`. Given [@KevinC's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155703/gratuitous-vertical-space-in-beamer-with-nested-list-environments-given-a-certai#comment356428_155703), the hunch is that this is related to glue in (La)TeX.</del> (See below.)

Second, I wanted to point out that this behavior persists even if one puts everything on one line *without* any space after ":", so it's still a mystery (at least to me, given my naive understanding of how things are set in horizontal mode), *why* there would be white space after the ":" that gets pushed to the next line. Does anyone have an explanation?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{itemize}
    \item{Actional verbs appeared in full \emph{be}-passive, full \emph{get}-passive, and active:\begin{enumerate}[(1)]\item{\ldots}\end{enumerate}}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

**Update 2**:

I've added the `beamer` tag again, as [@Thruston seems to think it has to do with how the `beamer` macros process space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155703/gratuitous-vertical-space-with-nested-list-environments-given-a-certain-line-len#comment357305_155905).

Comment: The second line is a little bit to long. Not enough to put last word in new line, bur enough to make empty space below next enumerating environment. try to make second line shorter for few character o longer for the same number of them /which can be hyphenated). Hopefully this will help.

Comment: A quick-fix to still keep it but not let it influence anything else is to use `\rlap{:}`...

Comment: @Zarko thanks for the tip, but, as I tried to convey in the question, I'm mostly interested in *why* it makes that empty space, if nothing is actually put on a new line. It just seems like strange and unintuitive behavior to me, so I'm curious why it's happening.

Comment: @Werner thanks for the suggestion. I'll use that for the sake of my presentation, though I'm still curious why this is actually happening. It seems like pretty unexpected behavior, at least to my naive mind.

Comment: It is as Zarko says, that the item without ":" is just enough to fit in one line. (Add `\tikz[overlay]\draw[gray](0,0)rectangle+(\textwidth,3);` after `\end{itemize}` to visualize the line width.) Adding an additional character, a colon or any *letter* for that matter, will produce too much width (due to gluing) to fit in one line, and thus push the white space to the next line. If you "kill off" inter-word space, for example, using `\spaceskip0pt` right after ":", there will be no extra space "pushed" to the next line.

Comment: @KevinC Using `spaceskip0pt` produces the exact same result for me. But anyway, why would there be space after the ":"? Since it was able to be fit on one line and since there is nothing after it in the `.tex` file, why would there be white space that gets pushed to the next line? If what you're suggesting is right, it would seem to me that this behavior (or something like it) should then be reproducible in (La)TeX? That is, it seems like you're suggesting it results from the way that white space is set horizontally?

Comment: Hmm... I got `\spaceskip0pt` working last night but not now. However, using `active:\spaceskip1pt` works. This is more of a diagnostic tool to detect where the problem might come from. The *TeXbook* does suggest that the stretchability will increase after a punctuation mark. Your case is slightly different, because if you change ":" to a letter say "i", the problem remains. Whatever the reason, I think it'll have to do with glues in LaTeX, although I don't have a good explanation for this.

Comment: @KevinC fair enough. And yes, I tried it with "l" as well, and it stays on the same line but there is still white space being pushed to a new line. If you try adding "b", though, then "activeb" gets pushed to the next line.

Answer (score 5):

You need to finish the paragraph in each top level item before you start the nested enumerate list.  The whole `enumerate` is being included in the `item` paragraph and this has caused the extra space in the output.

Try coding it like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Actional verbs appeared in full \emph{be}-passive, full \emph{get}-passive, and active

        \begin{enumerate}[(1)]
            \item \ldots
            \item \ldots
        \end{enumerate}

    \item Actional verbs appeared in full \emph{be}-passive, full \emph{get}-passive, and active:

        \begin{enumerate}[(1)]
            \item \ldots
        \end{enumerate}

\end{itemize}
```

Note the absence of `{` braces `}` after the `\item` control sequences, and the blank lines  to end the paragraph before the `enumerate` environments.

Actually the braces are irrelevant to the problem here because groups can span paragraphs, but you still don't really need them here, so best to leave them out.

Not ending the paragraph before the `enumerate` environments means that they are processed by TeX in horizontal mode rather than in vertical mode, and this changes the way that the Beamer format deals with them.  If you set `\tracingmacros=1` you will see that much of the processing is conditional on which mode you are in.  To answer your "why" question fully you would need to unravel the Beamer macros to see how the extra space in your longer line gets processed.

Comment: + 1 : But, I don't think the `{` and `}` are relevant. If you add back the braces into your MWE, the behavior is the exact same as it is without them. Additionally, I'm still not sure *why* there is any space after the colon that gets wrapped to the next line. You say "all the space between your colon and the `\begin{enumerate}` is being included", but there is *no* space after the colon. For example, this behavior persists even if you put the entire thing on one line with *no* space after the colon.

Comment: I agree the braces are irrelevant to the problem (since a group can span paragraphs) but you still don't need them.

Comment: I'll edit the reply to explain more about the space.

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification, though I'm hoping someone can still provide a more detailed explanation of why this is happening.

Comment: Good luck with that; the Beamer macros are a work of art.